# How to align group of mathematical expressions to the left?

Tags: math-mode, align

Here are a group of mathematical expressions:

```
$$arg\ \underset{\theta}{max} \underset{n}{\prod}P(Y_n|\theta)$$
$$=arg\ \underset{\theta}{max} \underset{n}{\prod}\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}$$
$$=arg\ \underset{\theta}{max} \sum log\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}$$
$$=arg\ \underset{\theta}{max} \sum[Y_n log\theta + (1-Y_n)log(1-\theta)] $$
Optimizing problem:
$$=-arg\ \underset{\theta}{min} \sum[Y_n log\theta + (1-Y_n)log(1-\theta)] $$
```

I am trying to align them to the left. I tried putting them inside `%\begin{align*} ... % \end{align*}` without `$$` signs. But no luck.

Comment: @Troy I've tried it but it does not serve my purpose.

Comment: Please describe your problem better, which code (MWE) did you tried, and what is still the problem, for example mark it in the screenshot added to your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete MWE, it's difficult to know what you're after, but I assume it's something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \underset{n}{\prod}P(Y_n|\theta) & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \underset{n}{\prod}\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n} \\
                                                                   & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \sum \log\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}           \\
                                                                   & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \sum[Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)]      \\
    \intertext{Optimizing problem:}
                                                                   & =-\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\min} \sum[Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)]     \\
\end{align*}
alternatively:
\begin{flalign*}
    & \arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \underset{n}{\prod}P(Y_n|\theta) \\
    & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \underset{n}{\prod}\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n} \\
    & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \sum \log\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}          \\
    & =\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\max} \sum[Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)]     \\
    \intertext{Optimizing problem:}
    & =-\arg\ \underset{\theta}{\min} \sum[Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)]    \\
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

alternatively, perhaps you'd like `flalign`:

[image]

Comment: I do not want the first line to contain a `=` sign.

Comment: @Dipto_Das if you provide a screenshot of your desired output, it'd be most helpful

Comment: @Dipto_Das see my update

Answer (score 1):

The following may be what you're looking for. Note the use of `\arg`, `\max`, `\min`, and `\log` to generate upright math-operator expressions. I've also replaced the two instances of `\underset{n}{\prod}` with `\prod_n`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \arg\max_\theta \prod_n P(Y_n\mid\theta)\\
&=\arg\max_\theta \prod_n \theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}\\
&=\arg\max_\theta \sum \log\bigl(\theta^{Y_n}(1-\theta)^{1-Y_n}\bigr)\\
&=\arg\max_\theta \sum [Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)]\\
\intertext{Optimizing problem:}
&-\arg\min_\theta \sum[Y_n \log\theta + (1-Y_n)\log(1-\theta)] 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does what I want, but it places everything in the center of the page. I want them all to start from the left margin. How can I do that?

Comment: @Dipto_Das - You could (a) switch from an `align*` environment to an `flalign*` environment and (b) add a `&` marker at the end of one of the math lines (but before the double line-break directive). E.g., change `\prod_n P(Y_n\mid\theta)` to `\prod_n P(Y_n\mid\theta)&`.